# Alternative syntax for do-while loop (using colon)

Tags: php, syntax, do-while

The [manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php) has references to alternative syntax for most control structures using colons, but I don't see one for a do-while loop.
Is it possible to do so? Something like this:

```
//Simple example
$arr = array(1,2,3,4,5,6);
$i = 0;

do :
    echo $arr[$i].'<br/>';
    $i++;
while($i < count($arr)) endwhile;
```

Comment: Since this does look very awkward, I'm not surprised it doesn't exist. :P

Comment: the alternative syntax should be avoided, especially if you're just writing flat-out php code, and using it "template-style".

Comment: @MarcB I'm not writing php code only, that was just for example.

Answer (score 6):

From the [manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.do.while.php):-

> There is just one syntax for do-while loops:

```
$i = 0;
do {
    echo $i;
} while ($i > 0);
```

Comment: Solves that..hehe. Thanks.